# Error correcting codes for stream of unkown size

Tags: error-correcting-codes, online-algorithms

Is there any algorithms like Reed Solomon that work for a stream of unknown data? The stream is finite but size is unknown until the stream ends.

I found some information about sliding window reed-solomon but that's pretty much it.

Comment: Reed-Solomon codes are generated with a fixed length. So what you can do is to slice the data and pad the last block in the end. Only the uncorrectable blocks will need to be retransmitted if necessary.

Comment: Is this the "sliding window reed solomon" algorigthm, or is just a shortcut for dealing with streams?

Comment: There seems to be a single paper about sliding-window R-S.